# Namespace and URLs Multi-site

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am pretty new to Python and Django, but I am working on a multi-site Django, created on 1.9

I am currently trying to make it work with Django 2.0 but I don't understand how the namespace and URL Works.

Here is the snippet that did not change :

```
/* Template */
<li><a href="{% url 'account:profile' %}">Profil {{ user.firstname.0 }}. {{ user.lastname }}</a></li>

/* Search project URLS.PY */
ACCOUNT_PATTERNS = [ url(r'^profil$', views.MyProfileFormView.as_view(), name='profile'), ]
urlpatterns = [ url(r'^gestion/', include(ACCOUNT_PATTERNS, namespace='account')), ]
```

Here is how it worked with the 1.9 version (Account is mapped in Search site) :

```
/* Main project URLS.PY */
from search import urls as search_urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^frontend/', include(frontend_urls)),
    url(r'^search/', include(search_urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And here is the 2.0 modified version I am trying to work with :

```
/* Main project URLS.PY */
temppatterns = [   
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('search/', include(search_urls)),
]
urlpatterns = temppatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

But when I go to /search, I got this

> NoReverseMatch at /search/
>   'account' is not a registered namespace

I do believe there was some huge change on the URLConf but I can't find any documentation to help me understand what and why.

To add some context :

- I don't have access on the old server
- Account is in Search. Search is a sub-site.
- If I understand correctly, we should be able to use namespace on alt site URLConf if we include the conf in the main project, but it's not the case here

If you need anything, feel free to ask me, I did a lot of works on this project already but now I just don't understand this part.

Should I rebuy all URLConf to include the namespace in the main project URLConf ?

Thanks in advance for helping me understand

Comment: `/* search projects did not change */` mean that under `/* search project URLS.PY */` nothing changed? Please include all related code snippets.

Comment: That's it. I edited to make it more readable, but there is like 200 lines in total. So I can add more things but I wanted to keep it digest. Thanks for your comments tho, don't hesitate to ask more things

Comment: Note that you don't have to use `path()` in Django 2.0 - `url()` will still work. Upgrading will be simpler if you change as little as possible until you get it working.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair, that's true, same goes for `re_path()` I was just testing it to see if it could change anything. But no. :/

Comment: Does your `search/urls.py` have an `app_name` set?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have writted it : `app_name = 'search'`. It did not in the 1.9 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have added `app_name = 'search'`, your `account` namespace is now nested inside the `search` namespace. Therefore you should use `search:account:` when reversing URLs, for example:

```
{% url 'search:account:profile' %}
```

Comment: Just to be sure. This is new in Django 2.0 ?
Is there a way to avoid the use of namespace ? I got a lot of issue back there trying to do some Include with namespace but no app_name.

Thanks in advance, and for your help

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. It looks like you need to add `search:` because you have added `app_name = 'search'`. If you don't want to do that, then don't set `app_name`. If you want to know more about the namespace changes to `include()`, see the [Django 1.9 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.9/#passing-a-3-tuple-or-an-app-name-to-include). Since these changes were in Django 1.9, you should be able to get the same code to work in Django 1.9 and 2.0.